# Creating a Label column for character variables

Tags: r, dataframe, label, summary

Suppose I have this example dataset with only character variables.

```
dxe1<-c("W07XXXA", "NULL", "3")
dxe1_poa<-c("Y","NULL","N")
dxe2<-c("NULL","NULL","NULL")
dxe2_poa<-c("NULL","NULL","NULL")
df3 <- data.frame(dxe1,dxe1_poa, dxe2,dxe2_poa)
```

I want to label the variables and so I created a label vector for them:

```
var.labels = c(dxe1="External Cause of Injury Diagnosis 1",
               dxe1_poa="External Cause of Injury Diagnosis 1 - Present on Admission", dxe2="External Cause of Injury Diagnosis 2", dxe2_poa="External Cause of Injury Diagnosis 2 - Present on Admission")

label(df3) = as.list(var.labels[match(names(df3), names(var.labels))])

label(df3)
```

My goal is to create a table similar to the one below, that is, I want to have a label column that gives the variable description. I only want the missing observations to display as the statistics and not min, max, mean, sd. They should be just n.a. like in the table below.

[image]

I am trying with the following set of codes:

```
df3 <- Filter(is.character, df3)
Variables <- names(df3)
Label <- label(df3)
Missing <- sapply(df3, function(x) sum(is.na(x)))
Type <- sapply(df3, function(x) {tmp <- class(x);if(length(x) > 1) tmp[2] else tmp[1]})
Min <- sapply(df3, function(x) min(x, na.rm = TRUE))
Max <- sapply(df3, function(x) max(x, na.rm = TRUE))
SD <- sapply(df3, function(x) format(round(sd(x, na.rm=TRUE), 2), nsmall = 2))
Mean <- sapply(df3, function(x) format(round(mean(x, na.rm=TRUE), 2), nsmall = 2))
#To get the Latex table for the rows 
knitr::kable(data.frame(Variables, Label, Missing, Type, Min, Max, Mean, SD, row.names = NULL), "latex")
```

However, with the above set of codes, the statistics of mean and SD are still displayed. I want to make them appear as "n.a" like the table above. Any suggestions? Also, I have minimum and maximum appearing in the character form. I just want the number forms to appear.

Comment: How will you show `min` and `max` of character variables? What do you mean by `I just want the number forms to appear.`

Comment: @RonakShah Hi, yes. Showing min and max of character variables doesn't make much sense. I am not sure why the table above is doing like that. But I want to show the missing values, the label, and the type. For the rest it could appear as "n.a." in the Latex output table. Right now, mine appear as NA instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this :

```
df3 <- Filter(is.character, df3)
Variables <- names(df3)
Label <- label(df3)
Missing <- sapply(df3, function(x) sum(is.na(x)))
Type <- sapply(df3, function(x) {tmp <- class(x);if(length(x) > 1) tmp[2] else tmp[1]})
Min <- 'n.a'
Max <- 'n.a'
SD <- 'n.a'
Mean <- 'n.a'
#To get the Latex table for the rows 
knitr::kable(data.frame(Variables, Label, Missing, Type, Min, Max, Mean, SD, row.names = NULL), "latex")
```